# how to get multiple values from one text field with delimiter and save each to database

Tags: java

actually I have 10-30 dummies to get the value from `txtCC`, but i'd only used 3 dummies for example below..

So how do I get each values and save it directly to my database without using dummy? It's a big deal coz' my code was too large to compile using those dummies..

THANKS for any help..

```
private void bSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                      
    // Save to database

    String cc = txtCC.getText();
    String delimiter = ",";
    String[] temp;
    temp = cc.split(delimiter);
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)

    if(i==0) {
        txtC1.setText(temp[0]);
        txtC2.setText("0");
        txtC3.setText("0"); }
    else if (i==1) { 
        txtC1.setText(temp[0]); 
        txtC2.setText(temp[1]);
        txtC3.setText("0"); }
    else if (i==2) { 
        txtC1.setText(temp[0]); 
        txtC2.setText(temp[1]); 
        txtC3.setText(temp[2]); }

    try {
        String cc1 = txtC1.getText(); int CC1 = Integer.parseInt(cc1);
        String cc2 = txtC2.getText(); int CC2 = Integer.parseInt(cc2);
        String cc3 = txtC3.getText(); int CC3 = Integer.parseInt(cc3);

        int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to save this record? ");
        if (opt == 0){
            if(!txtC1.getText().equals("0")) {
                stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                String sql = "Select * from tbl_liqinfo";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                rs.next();
                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateInt("CC", CC1);
                rs.insertRow();
                rs.close();
            }

            if(!txtC2.getText().equals("0")) {
                stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                String sql = "Select * from tbl_liqinfo";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                rs.next();
                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateInt("CC", CC2);
                rs.insertRow();
                rs.close();
            }

            if(!txtC3.getText().equals("0")) {
                stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                String sql = "Select * from tbl_liqinfo";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                rs.next();
                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateInt("CC", CC3);
                rs.insertRow();
                rs.close();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FrmEmpLiquidation.this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are dummies here?

Comment: Format correctly and paste again the code...

Comment: use String's split method.

Comment: Show us a sample of the input.

Comment: this is a sample the user will input: 1234,1235,1236  ... all i need is to get each value and save it to database.. in my sample, there are 3 values which means that there must be 3 rows saved in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using dummies, create simple small methods and make use of it. This will reduce you line of code. and also easy to understand.

private void bSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        // Save to database

```
    String cc = txtCC.getText();
    String delimiter = ",";
    String[] temp;
    temp = cc.split(delimiter);
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        insertData(temp[i]);

} 


public void insertData(final String data){
            txtC1.setText(data);

        try {
            String cc1 = txtC1.getText(); int CC1 = Integer.parseInt(cc1);

            int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to save this record? ");
            if (opt == 0){
                if(!txtC1.getText().equals("0")) {
                    stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                    String sql = "Select * from tbl_liqinfo";
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    rs.next();
                    rs.moveToInsertRow();
                    rs.updateInt("CC", CC1);
                    rs.insertRow();
                    rs.close();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FrmEmpLiquidation.this, err.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks here.. it helps a lot.. but another problem is since i have a  message box "Are you sure you want to save this record?" it always pop-ups multiple times depending on the number of values the textbox used. for example i put 3 values at once then the message box appears 3 times..